# Eigen: modify sparse matrix' triplet list, instead of using coeffRef

Tags: c++, eigen

I am facing the problem of assembling an `Eigen::SparseMatrix`. In reality it concerns a finite element system matrix, assembled by looping over elements and integration points. Below I have made the problem more abstract.

I initialize the matrix by first constructing a list of triplets (as suggested in the [Eigen documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html)). I then perform the assembly in concurrent loops using `coeffRef` (see example below). The question concerns the fact that `coeffRef` "performs a binary search", while I know exactly where each item is in the list of triplets (`T` below). More specifically:

- Is it more efficient to modify the list of triplets to avoid `coeffRef`, at the cost of having to reinitialize the sparse matrix?
- If one wants to modify a value in the list of triplets, is there something more elegant than

  ```
  T[i] = Trip(T[i].row(),T[i].col(),T[i].value()+X);
  ```

I realize that the answer may largely depend on the bandwidth of the matrix (i.e. how costly the search is), but there might be generic things to say about this.

#### Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> SpMat;
typedef Eigen::Triplet     <double> Trip;

int main(void)
{
  size_t N = 100;

  SpMat A(N,N);

  std::vector<Trip> T;
  T.reserve(3*N);

  for ( size_t i=0; i<N; ++i )
  {
    if ( i==0   ) T.push_back(Trip(i,i  ,-1.0));
    else          T.push_back(Trip(i,i-1,-1.0));

    T.push_back(Trip(i,i,+2.0));

    if ( i==N-1 ) T.push_back(Trip(i,0  ,-1.0));
    else          T.push_back(Trip(i,i+1,-1.0));
  }

  A.setFromTriplets(T.begin(),T.end());

  for ( size_t i=0; i<N; ++i )
    A.coeffRef(i,i) += static_cast<double>(i);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled using e.g.:

```
clang++ -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 test.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that as long as the coefficients accessed by `coeffRef` already exist in the matrix, then calling `coeffRef` should be faster than reconstructing the matrix from the triplet list.

You might also outsmart the binary search performed by `coeffRef` by directly accessing the underlying data structure with `A.valuePtr()[A.outerIndexPtr()[i]+some_offset] += ...`, assuming you can directly compute `some_offset` taking advantage of the known structure.

Finally, if you need to update all entries, you can also sequentially iterate over them using an `InnerIterator it` and update the entries with `it.valueRef() += ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The benefit of `coeffRef` is in any case also a cleaner code, which has great value too. From Eigen's source (`src/CompressedStorage.h`) it appears that the cost of the binary search is of the order of the bandwidth. I have used some sectioning algorithm before, but this is not what Eigen is doing right? Can you maybe clarify the costs of `setFromTriplets`?